# Number Theory - Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that every digit of $15n$ is either $8$ or $0$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that every digit of $15n$ is either $8$ or $0$.

This is one of the questions we presented in one session to contest preparation PUTNAM. It turns out that I can't get from the problem. Could someone just give me a hint? (Please, don't give me the answer. Simply, an argument that can help me advance in the problem or theorem might suffice.)

Comment: Hint: let $m=15n$. You need $m$ divisible by $5$ and divisible by $3$. Use divisibility rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try brute force with multiples of 15 but that might be too slow. You know that you are dealing with numbers consisting of only $0$s and $8$s. You also know that your number must be divisible by $15$ so it should end in $0$ and have $8$s in multiples of $3$.

You didn't want the answer but I can tell you that the smallest number with this property works.

Comment: this is not a hint !! read the question completely

Comment: @Elaqqad I read it. Please don't be rude.

Comment: @Elaqqad divisibility by 5 means it ends in a $0$ or a $5,$ which in this case it has to be $0$. Divisibility by three means the sum of the digits must divisible by $3$, in this case the sum of so many eights is divisible by $3$, and that is the hint and it is sufficient.

Comment: The answer was edited after the first post, and in the first answer the solution was given

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use different combinations of 0 and 8 to generate the numbers. Since these numbers need to be divisible by 3 and 5, you need the last digit to be zero and the sum of digits to be a multiple of 3.